# Reactstrap Collapse not working within React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, reactstrap

I've been trying to get my React component to work with the Collapse but I cannot seem to get my component to collapse correctly. Right now it will collapse temporarily when the div is clicked, but it will automatically reopen and not actually collapse any of the information needed. This component is taking multiple "modules" and turning them into their own cards. I've tried using a button instead of a div for the "onClick" and have tried with and without the reactstrap Card and CardBody components.

I'm thinking that the useState hook is somehow getting lost with my other props? Any help would be appreciated.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Container, Collapse, Card, CardBody } from "reactstrap";
import ReplayCard from "./ReplayCard";
import AttachmentCard from "./AttachmentCard";

const ModuleCard = (props) => {
    const module = props.cardID;
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
    const toggle = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  return (
    <div className="moduleCard">
      <div onClick={toggle}>
        <h2>{module.m_title}</h2>
        <h5>Replay Date: {module.m_date}</h5>
      </div>
      <Collapse isOpen={isOpen}>
        <h5>
          {module.m_description}
        </h5>
        <h3>{module.m_title} Video(s)</h3>
        <Container className="ReplayCard" fluid={true}>
          {module.m_replay &&
            module.m_replay.map((value, index) => {
              return (
                <ReplayCard
                  key={index}
                  cardID={index}
                  video={value.video}
                  text={value.text}
                />
              );
            })}
        </Container>
        <h3>{module.m_title} Link(s)</h3>
        <Container className="AttachmentCard" fluid={true}>
          {module.m_attachment &&
            module.m_attachment.map((value, index) => {
              return (
                <AttachmentCard
                  key={index}
                  cardID={index}
                  text={value.text}
                  link={value.link}
                />
              );
            })}
        </Container>
      </Collapse>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ModuleCard;
```

The useState does seem to be changing from true to false when a console.log is inserted to the togged but still isn't actually triggering any changes.

Comment: i don't see problem with the usage of `useState`. Try to set collapse to true, `<Collapse isOpen={true}>`, see if this line works first. If it works, then put a console.log after `const toggle = ()` to print `isOpen` and see if `onClick` triggers this flag.

Comment: the boolean variables are changing on click, but I'm also getting the following error in the console for every click (edited my question above with the warning)

Comment: The warning you attached is clearly telling you the issue. Check both of your map() if any of those is returning duplicate value. BTW, index is a 2nd parameter in map(value, index). There are chances that duplicate data is being passed in the key prop.

Comment: @SaurabhSharma - Thanks! I knew I was missing something there. That seemed to do the trick for the error. I've got to make a note of the two parameters in the future.
The collapse still doesn't seem to be triggering properly, however.